# Spring application context external properties?

Tags: spring, properties

i have a Spring application and its working well so far. Now i want the properties file in an external config folder and not in the packed jar to change things without the need to repack. This is what i got:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<!-- <property name="locations" value="classpath:/springcontext.properties"/>  -->
<property name="locations" value ="config/springcontext.properties" />
```

The outcommented one is working and the other one i dont get to work :/ Can someone help?

Edit:
Thx 4 comments so far.

Maybe my question wasnt clear enough :). I perform a Maven build and everything will be packaged and i want this folder to be NOT in the package nut next to the outcomming jar and in this folder i want the properties file. possible?

Comment: Try with a singular `location`, although `locations` should work. Also try removing the leading `/` from the classpath reference.

Comment: anyone can help on the new question?

Comment: @DennisIch How did you end up fixing this ? I am facing a similar question

Comment: <property name="locations" value ="file://config/springcontext.properties" /> and just copy it to the application folder should work ;). Im using a mvn "ant task" for the copy job.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:spring/*.properties" />
```

If you place it somewhere in the classpath in a directory named spring (change names/dirs accordingly), you can access with above

```
<property name="locations" value ="config/springcontext.properties" />
```

this will be pointing to web-inf/classes/config/springcontext.properties

Comment: its not a web application its a standalone with some command line functionality and for that i need it outside the jar.

Comment: Well then it is right next to your jar file if it is not a web project

Answer (score 48):

You can try something like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder 
        location="${ext.properties.dir:classpath:}/servlet.properties" />
```

And define `ext.properties.dir` property in your application server / jvm, otherwise the default properties location "classpath:/" (i.e., classes dir of .jar or .war) would be used:

```
-Dext.properties.dir=file:/usr/local/etc/
```

BTW, very useful [blog post](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring/).

Answer (score 13):

You can use file prefix to load the external application context file some thing like this

```
  <context:property-placeholder location="file:///C:/Applications/external/external.properties"/>
```

Comment: Also works as `location` property of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

Answer (score 11):

[This](http://www.blog.openshell.in/2012/11/access-external-property-file-in-spring-application-context-using-propertyplaceholderconfigurer/) blog can help you. The trick is to use SpEL (spring expression language) to read the system properties like `user.home`, to read user home directory using SpEL you could use 
`#{ systemProperties['user.home']}` expression inside your bean elements. For example to access your properties file stored in your home directory you could use the following in your PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, it worked for me.

```
 <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>file:#{ systemProperties['user.home']}/ur_folder/settings.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks this help for me

Answer (score 6):

This question is kind of old, but wanted to share something which worked for me. Hope it will be useful for people who are searching for some information accessing properties in an external location.

This is what has worked for me.

1. Property file contents:

   ```
   PROVIDER_URL=t3://localhost:8003,localhost:8004
   ```
2. `applicationContext.xml` file contents: (Spring 3.2.3)

   Note: `${user.home}` is a system property from OS.

   ```
   <context:property-placeholder system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" location="file:${user.home}/myapp/latest/bin/my-env.properties"/>

   <bean id="appsclusterJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
       <property name="environment">
           <props>
               <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
               <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${PROVIDER_URL}</prop>
           </props>
       </property>
   </bean>
   ```

`${PROVIDER_URL}` got replaced with the value in the properties the file

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to add your external config folder to the classpath of the java process. That's how I've often done it in the past.

Comment: It seems Spring's `property-placeholder` isn't capable of loading property-files outside of the package where application context is defined (see http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?87994-Classpath*-in-context-property-placeholder-doesnt-pick-system-classpath&p=295698#post295698). How did you achieve loading external property-files?

Comment: Umm... adding what into manifest file? The `MANIFEST.MF` file resides inside a package, so how could it help?

Answer (score 1):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/apps/tomcat/ath/ath_conf/pcr.application.properties" />
```

This works for me.
Local development machine path is C:\apps\tomcat\ath\ath_conf and in server /apps/tomcat/ath/ath_conf

Both works for me