# How to use different configuration for deployment?

Tags: maven, deployment, web-deployment

I am currently dealing with the deployment of my web-server which is why I am facing a presumably very common problem: Configuration files

As a very straight forward example let's take a database. I have a local *`database.xml`* which contains the data source which I use on my local machine:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mz_db" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="pg" />
</bean>
```

but of course, I am connecting to a different database once I deploy the server. So what are my options here? I would like to have this as centralized as possible to prevent wrong files being deployed here. I am sure that maven can be used for this somehow.

I was thinking about doing something like creating two *`config/`* directories

```
WEB-INF/config/
WEB-INF/config-dev/
```

and use *`config-dev/`* per default without the exception of the `deploy` phase or something like this. I am not sure if this can be done or if this is the best way of doing it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: rule in general keep configuration out of application. which application server are you using?

Comment: @Hishamkh I am not sure if I understand. What do you mean with "*keep configuration out of application*"? I am using Spring which comes with quite some `applicatoinContext-*.xml` stuff and there's stuff like the database connection defined like you see it in my question. Not sure what to answer by application server :D I am using Tomcat currently but I might have to switch to Jetty.

Comment: You can use [external propery files](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).
Checkout this [stackoverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270290/spring-application-context-external-properties)

Comment: you can take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin that removes the need for profiles and produces packages for each environment in one go...

Comment: @khmarbaise Looks promising! I'll take a look. Thanks :)

Comment: @mac That's not really what I need here. All configuration files are always at the same place. No matter where the server is actually running. The my problem is more packaging related. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @khmarbaise How does such a `*.properties` look like? O_o

Comment: @displayname What do you mean?

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't understand how these `.properties` files have to look like. How can I define certain files which I want to use for certain environments etc.

Comment: You can put different files  (and of course different file types) into the appropriate folders and they will be packaged into a the resulting archive. It is not limited to `.properties` you can use any kind of file...Those property files are only given as an example...