# spring-boot profiles : resources/profiles/application-*.properties

Tags: spring-boot

I have a lot of profiles, I want to put it to `/profiles` folder, I do not want to put it to `classpath:/,classpath:/config/,file:./,file:./config/`, I saw the Class `ConfigFileApplicationListener`, Is there any other way?

Comment: you need to be more specific. What does your project setup look like. Where is the profiles folder? How does the application find that folder when run? Are you packaging the config files with your app? Do you want to provide them separately? Do you want them on the classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what you are asking, but it sounds like you want to put your profile-specific properties files in a /profiles directory, rather than one of the default search locations.

In the [ConfigFileApplicationListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener.html), you can specify /profiles using `setSearchLocations()`

> Alternative search locations and names can be specified using
>   setSearchLocations(String) and setSearchNames(String).

From the Javadocs for `ConfigFileApplicationListener.setSearchLocations()`:

> Set the search locations that will be considered as a comma-separated
>   list. Each      search location should be a directory path (ending in
>   "/") and it will be prefixed    by the file names constructed from
>   setSearchNames(String) search names and profiles (if any)
>   plus file extensions supported by the properties loaders.       Locations
>   are considered in the order specified, with later items taking
>   precedence      (like a map merge).

Add the custom `ConfigFileApplicationListener` to the `SpringApplication` via the [addListeners() method](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/application-listener/) before calling `run()`.

**Alternative Method**

As a somewhat easier workaround, I find @masted's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270290/spring-application-context-external-properties/8307646#8307646) this method to be much easier. The only downside is you need to add an environment variable,

`-Dext.properties.dir=classpath:/profiles/`

followed by whatever environment you want to point to.

Comment: Edit your question and add some more details (stacktrace, reproducible example code, etc). Otherwise it's just a guessing game.